# When Capturing City-States do bonuses remain?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

What I mean is do the City-States type bonuses (Extra Food, Religion, Culture, Special Luxuries, etc) remain with the city when captured.

So if I capture a Faith-based City-State with I gain the +2 Faith per turn the City-State had or are those Owner specific and not City specific?

Another Example: If I capture a City-State with porcelain, will I keep the porcelain once it's my city?

Comment: Sidenote: you only have bonuses when you befriend/allied a City state. I think this is worth mentioning.:)

Comment: I knew that, but I guess it makes a lot more sense as to why it doesn't remain when you say it lol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you capture a City-State, it is no longer a City-State, and you do not receive the bonuses due to being a City-State's ally. So that bonus Faith, Culture, Food, etc. disappears entirely, and Porcelain and Jewelry also disappears. Only Mercantile City-States produce Porcelain or Jewelry, so it's treated like any other City-State bonus and it goes away.

Once it's your city, it acts just like any other city you've captured, and it does not have any special bonuses.

Comment: That is probably the reason I will never be a City-State Warmonger haha. That's kind of really lame. I think a mod that changes this would be really cool, make their bonuses a building or something. Then when you take a Meritime City-State your allies gain +1 food at their capital. Would make Warmonging City-States look less awful :P

Comment: @Shelby115, I'm sure that's exactly why it works that way. City-States are such easy targets that you really need a reason why *not* to conquer them for the glory of the empire. (Aside from the optimization of "I don't want to have to pay for a Courthouse.")

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I never conquer City-States because of the Diplomatic penalty that accompanies it. I feel like there should be -some- benefit somewhere. But yeah I guess everyone would do it if there was a bonus for everyone.